# Why did they choose green lighting for the lounge shootout in John Wick 3?

Tags: production, john-wick-chapter-3-parabellum, lighting

During the lounge shootout in *John Wick 3*, the lounge is lit in green, as shown here:

[image]

Was this intended to be a homage to *The Matrix*? If not, then why was green lighting chosen for this scene?

Comment: I've removed the secondary question about the "guns, lots of guns" line, as questions on Stack Exchange should only ask one question at a time. If you want to know whether that was a reference to *The Matrix*, you should post that as a separate question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per Cinematography, Dan Laustsen  it was done for the exclusive look:

> “It was really expensive in terms of human resource to install a hundred metres of LED, but I didn’t want to do a shootout that would look just like any other shootout,” he explains.[IBC](https://www.ibc.org/trends/behind-the-scenes-john-wick-3/3840.article)

Also from [American cinematographer](https://ascmag.com/articles/john-wick-chapter-3-slayin-in-the-rain)

> “I love the look of that scene,” Laustsen remarks. “With the blue light coming through the windows, the green LEDs, and the red in the background, you have the film’s three main colors in one big shootout.”

Answer (score 2):

During [an interview](https://www.koimoi.com/hollywood-news/keanu-reeves-draws-a-parallel-between-john-wick-the-matrix-leaving-fans-mind-boggled/), Reeves himself said the following:

> “I mean we literally do a line from ‘The Matrix’ in ‘John Wick: Chapter 3′, and it’s in the nomenclature…’The Matrix’ has the oracle, ‘John Wick’ has the elder…you can just keep going. I think that Chad was influenced by the way which Wachowskis created the Matrix world, mythology and I think he has done a really good job taking those influences and making it Wick!,” he added.

Based on that, especially "Chad was influenced by the way which Wachowskis created the Matrix world" part, we can safely assume the green lighting was indeed "taken" from The Matrix, as it's part of the way Matrix world was built.